# Method not allowed Post in django

Tags: django, post

when i try to add a post method in my app it shows this message :

Method not allowed (Post): HTTP/1.1 405 0

*views.py*

```
class AddTeamView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = TeamForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        
        return render(
            request,
            'add_team.html',
            context
        )
```

*add_team.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Add a Team
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action="/add_team/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<!-- this form content is called from the view.py/context-->
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="اضافة "/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'add_team/$', AddTeamView.as_view(), name='add-team-view'),
]
```

*settings.py*

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms


class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='اسم الفريق')
    details = forms.CharField(label='تفاصيل الفريق')
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You don't seem to have defined a post method.

Comment: i don't understand you?

Comment: Your view clearly only has a get method.

Comment: so how i can fix it ?

Comment: Write a post method which does what you want to happen when you submit the form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like Daniel Roseman's comment says, you need to add a post method to your view. When you submit the filled form the HTTP request from your browser is a POST, not a GET.

Check out the the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/) for an example of how to organize a basic class view like you are trying to use with a post and get method.

Here is the documentation example modified for your case:

```
class AddTeamView(View):
    form_class = TeamForm
    template_name = 'add_team.html'

    # Handle GET HTTP requests
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    # Handle POST GTTP requests
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i just fix it like you and Daniel's said

Comment: the last line `return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})` should be indented once more